# Any Chrome extension or plugin can automatically save webpages viewed?

Tags: google-chrome, web-crawler, extension

I am looking for a software or browser extension (better with Chrome) which can save all the webpages I viewed automatically on local.

As far as I know, there is one with Firefox called ScrapBook, but does not support FireFox after ver 60.